# PowerMTA Startup error: Error loading DNS configuration: Error parsing IP address "2a02:c207::2:53": syntax error

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, email

```
service pmta restart
Stopping PowerMTA: [  OK  ]
Starting PowerMTA: [FAILED]

pmtad --debug
Startup error: Error loading DNS configuration: Error parsing IP address "2a02:c207::2:53": syntax error
```

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many programs require IPv6 address literals to appear in brackets, e.g.:

```
[2a02:c207::2:53]
```